# Apply a function with lists like inputs

Tags: python, map-function

I want to create a new list (V) from other lists (a, b, c) and using a function, but I would like to take advantage of python and apply the function to the three lists and not element by element.

For example, I have the lists a, b and c; and the result after apply the function should be V. Thanks.

```
def mag(a, b, c):
    # something sophisticated
    return (a+b)*c

a = [1, 5, 7]
b = [4, 8, 3] 
c = [2, 6, 3]
V = [10, 78, 30]
```

Comment: Applying `mag` (as written) to the elements of `a`, `b`, and `c` does not produce `V`. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map (lists are iterables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily do this with the `map` function:

```
V = list(map(mag, a, b, c))
```

Comment: Whoa, this is cool. I had no idea `map` would partially apply the function with each iterable. Really nice answer.

Comment: Me neither.  Works under python 27 as well, where `map(mag, a, b, c)` would thus be enough.

Answer (score 3):

You want to first zip the arguments, then map the function on the unpacked tuples:

```
from itertools import starmap

starmap(mag, zip(a,b,c))
```

See [here](https://ideone.com/uTNa5L) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

What about using only built-in functions? Like [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
>>> [mag(a_, b_, c_) for a_,b_,c_ in zip(a, b, c)]
[10, 78, 30]
```

Plus another python buit-in function, [map](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#map) which returns an
iterator and thus makes things go faster and ends up saving memory:

```
>>> gen = map(lambda uple:mag(*uple), zip(a, b, c))
>>> list(gen)
[10, 78, 30]
```

Comment: Thanks, but the example above was only an example, I need to use the function

Comment: @user140259. Better now ?

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution is to use `map` and `lambda`

```
In [16]: list(map(lambda p: mag(*p), zip(a, b, c)))
Out[16]: [10, 78, 30]
```