# Looping lists through a function with multiple variables

Tags: python, numpy

so i have generated random values for a few of the variables in my function. These are in lists.

I can't seem to figure out how to loop these lists through the function and output the t values?

Thanks

```
def d_oscil(l,w,f,t):
    return np.exp(-l*t)*np.cos(w*t-f)

t_list = np.arange(0 , 5 , 0.001)
y_list = d_oscil(1,np.pi*2,1,t_list)

plt.figure(num=0,dpi=150)
plt.plot(t_list,np.exp(-t_list),color = 'red' , linestyle = '--' )
plt.plot(t_list, y_list)
plt.title( 'Graph of y = exp(-lt) cos(wt-f)' )
# Draw l ines to mark 0 on the x and y axes
plt.axhline( 0 , color= 'black' , linestyle = '-' )
plt.axvline ( 0 , color = 'black' , linestyle = '-' )
# Set the y-axis & x-axis limits
plt.ylim(-1.2 , 1.2)
plt.xlim(0 , 5)
plt.title( 'Damped Oscillator')
plt.xlabel( 'Time')
plt.ylabel( 'Displacement')
plt.show()

t_random_list = []
for i in range(0,5):
    n = random.uniform(0,5)
    t_random_list.append(n)

l_random_list = []
for i in range(0,5):
    n = random.gauss(1,0.5)
    l_random_list.append(n)

f_random_list = []
for i in range(0,5):
    n = random.gauss(1,0.5)
    f_random_list.append(n)

w = np.pi*2
```

Comment: To be clear: you want to have a loop that will call `d_oscil(l_random_list[0], w, t_random_list[0], f_random_list[0])`, then `d_oscil(l_random_list[1], w, t_random_list[1], f_random_list[1])` etc.? Where the `w` value is constant, but the others are taken pairwise from the random lists? Do you want to use a Numpy-specific solution for iterating through these values (this can be more efficient, but you will have to create Numpy arrays instead of lists in the first place)? What do you want to *do with* the `d_oscil` results? Is the code for the plot relevant to the *question you are asking*?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52750669/apply-a-function-with-lists-like-inputs help?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be something like:

```py
w = np.pi*2
values = [d_oscil(l, w, f, t) for l, f, t in zip(l_random_list, f_random_list, t_random_list)]
```

Iterate over the three lists simultaneously and call the func. `values` will contain a list of the returned values from d_oscil for each item in the three lists. You can read more about [zip here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).